# Convert QuerySet with calculate field to one or more json basead from key

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying convert a QuerySet in a json to use with chartjs, but I've some problems with the convertion. eg:

```
_queryset = CheckOut.objects.filter(date_service__year = this_year).values_list('date_service__month').\
    annotate(total=Sum('profit')).order_by('date_service__month')

dt = _queryset
```

if a print this variable "**dt**", in template `{{ dt }}` I've this values printed

```
<QuerySet [(8, Decimal('300.00')), (9, Decimal('729.00'))]>
```

How I do to separate: **month** and **total**(from annotate) in two json, like this:

```
[8,9] <- month

[300, 729] <- total price
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data is a list of key/value pairs, you could create a dictionary and then extract the values using the `keys()` and `values()` methods. Using an `OrderedDict` would ensure the order is preserved.

For example:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

_queryset = CheckOut.objects.filter(date_service__year = this_year).values_list('date_service__month').\
    annotate(total=Sum('profit')).order_by('date_service__month')

dt = OrderedDict(_queryset)  # Wrap queryset with an OrderedDict

extracted = {
    'months': list(dt.keys()),  # Extract the list of months
    'totals': list(dt.values()) # Extract the list of totals
}
```